# How do you make sense of this rawest of thought experiments about length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I've seen dozens of iterations of thought experiments demonstrating how length contraction supposedly worked to preserve the invariance of the speed of light ***c*** across reference frames, all involving multiple clocks, rods, mirrors or other contraptions that serve to reflect a light signal in some way at some point.

But let's do away with those and break it down to just the essential parts:

**1. One observer (Alice) on earth, and**

**2. another (Bob) in a spaceship moving at literally *any* arbitrary speed below *c*.**

**Now, suppose that Bob flicked on a flashlight for a brief moment mid-flight, into the void of space with no particular target.**

Supposedly, length contraction and time dilation would have acted to "prevent" the light emitted by Bob's flashlight from exceeding ***c*** in either of Alice's or Bob's reference frames.

My question is... **HOW?**

For Bob's flashlight to emit photons that move exactly at the speed of light *in Alice's reference frame*, wouldn't Bob have to be **completely** at rest with Alice? His spaceship, flashlight and body could contract and slow ("dilate") all they like, but at the end of the day, wouldn't **any** movement at all need to be added to the speed of the photons emitted from Bob's flashlight in this scenario?

Comment: Usually I see the two postulates used to derive length contraction, time dilation, and relativity of simultaneity. Are you wanting us to assume length contraction, time dilation, and relativity of simultaneity and use those to derive the second postulate? It seems backwards but it can be done.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking anything remotely that metaphysical. Just pretty straightforward addition of speeds. If an observer in motion is to emit a light signal without said signal exceeding the speed of light, then doesn't that necessitate that the observer not be moving at all? Since otherwise, the light signal would just be c + the speed of the observer regardless of how much dilation and contraction they're subject to? Note especially Alice's perspective here.

Comment: I didn’t say anything about metaphysics. I was just trying to clarify what you are asking. Are you wanting us to derive the invariance of c from some assumptions? If so, what assumptions are allowed? If not, what are you wanting?  Please clarify

Comment: Are you reasoning from the assumption that length contraction means the contraction of physical objects, but not the length of trajectories through empty space?

Comment: As far as I understand, I'm only referring to the established conventions of special relativity here. c is constant regardless of the motion of observers, and length contraction and time dilation follow to preserve this invariance of c. I put this into a basic thought experiment here. My question is simply: How do length contraction (and time dilation) preserve the invariance of c without necessitating every observer be at rest with any other observer?

Comment: @g s   To Alice in this setup, it's just Bob and the contents of his spaceship that are length contracted, right?

Comment: There's your mistake, then. To Alice, *every length that an observer comoving with Bob could measure* parallel to their relative velocity is contracted. That is to say, Bob's entire coordinate system is contracted along the axis parallel to Alice's relative velocity. The space ship is just the only object that Alice can readily see that is obviously comoving with Bob.

Comment: I see. I'm still having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around it though. If no other objects were comoving with Bob in Alice's frame, then aren't these lengths of hypothetical other moving observer trajectories merely... well, hypothetical? Not "real" in any meaningful way compared to Bob and his actual spaceship?

Comment: For instance: Suppose Bob was on his way to a planet as his destination. To Alice, the length between Bob's points of departure and destination remains the same and it's only the spaceship that's contracted, right?

Comment: Bob's coordinate system is comoving with Bob. Bob's coordinate system is a fact about Bob, not the rest of the universe, but the measurements that Bob makes using his coordinate system, compared to the measurements that Alice makes using a similar, coordinate system (relative to her reference frame), are facts about the universe. Suppose the planet is comoving with Alice. Then Alice measures the distance to the planet to be $L_0$, and Bob measures the distance to the planet to be $L_0/\gamma(v)$.

Comment: I would suggest finding some sample problems and working through them. Intuition comes from exposure. Most introductory relativity questions don't require anything but algebra.

Comment: Ok, so far so good. But then Alice observes Bob's flashlight emitting a beam that evolves at **c** even though Bob was **already** moving at a **fraction of c** when he turned on his flashlight? I can't help feel like that doesn't make sense. Or am I still confusing something?

Comment: To simply answer your question, the velocity addition formula in SR that we need for our purposes is $V=(v±u)/(1±vu/c²)$. Where V is the speed of object (light in our case) according to Alice, u is the speed of object according to Bob and v is the velocity of Bob according to Alice, plugging u=c, we get V=c, as it should. For more on this you can grab any undergrad mechanics book like Tai chow, Kleppner and Kolenkow, Morin, Irodov, etc

Comment: Yes, the speed of light is the same in all reference frames.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. It does make more sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding at least two aspects of SR. Firstly, in the example you give, the length contraction of the spaceship itself is irrelevant. Secondly, time dilation and length contraction don't explain the constancy of the speed of light in the scenario you describe- what does explain it is the relativity of simultaneity.

More specifically, the time dilation formula is a special case that only applies to the interval between two events that occur in the same place in one frame and in two different places in another. That doesn't apply in the example you describe.

To see what is happening, imagine that Bob flashes a light just as Alice walks past him heading left at one metre per second, and the light goes off to the left and to the right.

Now suppose in Bob's frame there are two detectors, one being 299,792,458 metres to the left of him, and the other being the same distance to the right. After exactly a second, in his frame, the light will arrive at the left detector and at the right detector, so its speed is the same in both directions.

Now in Alice's frame, the light set off when she was alongside Bob, but by the time the light has reached the detector to the left of Bob (which is the direction in which Alice is heading), Alice will have moved closer to that detector by about one metre, so the light will only have travelled about 299,792,457m in the time period between leaving Alice and arriving at the left-hand detector, so in order for the speed of light to be the same for Alice as it is for Bob, slightly less than a second must have passed in Alice's frame.

When the light heading in the opposite direction meets the right hand detector, however, that detector is about a meter further from Alice than it is from Bob, so in order for light to have the same speed in that direction in Alice's frame, slightly more than a second must have passed in Alice's frame.

So you should be able to see that the only way for the speed of light to be the same for Alison as it is for Bob  is if slightly less than a second passes in Alice's frame in one direction, and slightly more than a second passes in the other direction. Time dilation can't possibly account for that, because time dilation would have the same effect in both directions.